# Inserting multiple values with Oracle Insert Into...Values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to run the following command in Oracle 11g but keep getting an error of 'commmand not properly ended'. I am new to Oracle and I haven't been able to find anything about insert multiple value sets (unless they are selected from a table which in this case they are not)....

```
INSERT INTO category (catcode, catdesc)
VALUES ('BUS', 'BUSINESS'),
    ('CHN', 'CHILDREN'),
    ('COK', 'COOKING'),
    ('COM', 'COMPUTER'),
    ('FAL', 'FAMILY LIFE'),
    ('FIT', 'FITNESS'),
    ('SEH', 'SELF HELP'),
    ('LIT', 'LITERATURE'),
    ('CHN', 'CHILDREN'),
    ('BUS', 'BUSINESS');
```

If this syntax is completely off, then how can I insert multiple values in one statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always use `insert . . . select` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO category (catcode, catdesc)
    select 'BUS', 'BUSINESS' from dual union all
    select 'CHN', 'CHILDREN' from dual union all
    select 'COK', 'COOKING' from dual union all
    select 'COM', 'COMPUTER' from dual union all
    select 'FAL', 'FAMILY LIFE' from dual union all
    select 'FIT', 'FITNESS' from dual union all
    select 'SEH', 'SELF HELP' from dual union all
    select 'LIT', 'LITERATURE' from dual union all
    select 'CHN', 'CHILDREN' from dual union all
    select 'BUS', 'BUSINESS' from dual;
```

Answer (score 9):

Try like this,

```
INSERT ALL 
     INTO category (catcode, catdesc) VALUES ('BUS', 'BUSINESS')
     INTO category (catcode, catdesc) VALUES ('CHN', 'CHILDREN')
     INTO category (catcode, catdesc) VALUES ('COK', 'COOKING')
     INTO category (catcode, catdesc) VALUES ('COM', 'COMPUTER')
     INTO category (catcode, catdesc) VALUES ('FAL', 'FAMILY LIFE')
     INTO category (catcode, catdesc) VALUES ('FIT', 'FITNESS')
     INTO category (catcode, catdesc) VALUES ('SEH', 'SELF HELP')
     INTO category (catcode, catdesc) VALUES ('LIT', 'LITERATURE')
     INTO category (catcode, catdesc) VALUES ('CHN', 'CHILDREN')
     INTO category (catcode, catdesc) VALUES ('BUS', 'BUSINESS')
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

Refer [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/insert_rows.php) for more in detail.